# React component not rerendering on props change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that renders correctly on page load, but when props changes, doesn't re-render. The console.log(list) below indicates that render() is being called and that the list array contains the right data but the page is no longer re-rendering.

If I add a setState in componentDidUpdate() I just get an infinite loop.

Whats causing this?

here is the app that calls the siteList.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Filters from './Components/List/Filters.js';
import SiteList from './Components/List/SiteList.js';


class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      sites : [{ _id: {}, urpn: 0, wifi: false, fibre: false, location: { 'coordinates' : [0, 0] } }], 
      filters: {Properties: false, Customers: false, Coverage: false, Network: false, Fibre50: false, Fibre200: false, Fibre500: false  }, 
      page: 1, 
      pageSize: 25,
    };

  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getSites();
  };

  setSearch = (data) => {

    var state = this.state;
    state.search = data;
    this.setState(state);

    console.log( "state search" + this.state.search );

    this.getSites();
  }

  setType = (data) => {
    var filters = this.state.filters;

    if(this.state.filters[data] == true){
      filters[data] = false;
    }else{
      filters[data] = true;
    }

    var state = this.state;
    state.filters = filters;
    this.setState(state);

    this.getSites();
  };

  getSites = () => {
    if (typeof controller !== "undefined") {
      controller.abort();
    }

    if ("AbortController" in window) {
      var controller = new AbortController;
      var signal = controller.signal;
    }

    var url = '/wisp/public/api/sites?';

    if(this.state.filters){
      var filtersString = JSON.stringify(this.state.filters);
      url = url + '&filters=' + filtersString;
    }

    if(this.state.search){
      //var searchString = JSON.stringify(this.state.search);
      var searchString = this.state.search;
      url = url + '&search=' + searchString;
    }

    if(this.state.page){
      var pageString = JSON.stringify(this.state.page);
      var pageSizeString = JSON.stringify(this.state.pageSize);
      url = url + '&page=' + pageString;
      url = url + '&pageSize=' + pageSizeString;
    }


    this.setState({loading: true}, () => {
      fetch(url, {signal})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          sites : data.sites, 
          count : data.count, 
        }
        , () => {
          console.log("this.state.sites");
          console.log(this.state.sites);
          this.setState({loading: false});
        });
      });
    }); 

  };

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="section list">
        <Filters filters={this.state.filters} setType={this.setType} setSearch={this.setSearch} runexport={this.runexport} />
        <SiteList
          sites={this.state.sites}
          passiveSites={this.state.passiveSites}
          activeSites={this.state.activeSites}
        />

      </section>
    );
  }
}

 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

here is the Sitelist

```
export default class SiteList extends React.Component {

  render() {

    const list = this.props.sites.map((item, i) => {
        return <div key={i} className="box">
                <SiteForm
                  item={item}
                />
              </div>
    });

    console.log(list); 

    return (
      <div className="container">
          {list}
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

The site form is just a json.Stringify print and the issue still occurs. I can't create a minimum working version on the code as it relies on a private API. This is as small as I can make the code base.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: what if you change `{list}` directly to `{this.props.sites.map((item, i) => {
        return <div className="box"> <SiteForm key={i} item={item} /> </div>
    })}`?

Comment: When rendering a list of elements, the `key` should be on the top-level elements in the list. In your list, the key is on the `SiteForm`, not the `div` it's in.

Comment: @messerbill - That wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: can you show us all the codes of the SiteList file?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yea i thought so but i was not sure

Comment: @RaphaelEstrada That is the complete code of SiteList

Comment: At the point you believe this.props.sites has been updated, could you confirm that you do see that `console.log(list);` executing and you can see the updated data? If so, there is nothing wrong with `SiteList` and I would suspect it's SiteForm not updating

Comment: I can confirm that console.log(list); has the right information.

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/uf5kxqL1/) if I make reasonable guesses at what you're doing beyond what's in the question. (Do note the error from the dev copy of React warning you about the key thing.) Again: Please update the question with an MCVE.

Comment: @user2340824 - There *is* something wrong with SiteList, as I pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55847189/react-component-not-rerendering-on-props-change#comment98356485_55847189). It just doesn't account for the OP's described symptom.

Comment: I can't add a runnable version of my code as it relies on a private API. I've updated the code after a bunch more testing to make it cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue ended up being with siteform, my solution was to add

```
componentDidUpdate(previousProps, previousState) {

    if (previousProps.item !== this.props.item) {
        var temp = _.cloneDeep(this.props.item);
        temp.components = undefined;
        this.setState({item: temp });
    }

    if (previousProps.components !== this.props.components) {
        var temp2 = []; 
        temp2 = _.cloneDeep(this.props.item.components); 
        this.setState({components: temp2 }); 
    }
}
```

I have a feeling that the clonedeep is overkill, but it's neater this way.